# Junit Test report (XML/HTML) not generated in android studio

Tags: android, junit, android-gradle-plugin

```
public class StringUtilsTests extends TestCase {

    String message;
    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        message = "33,333";
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public void testCommaToSpaces() {
        String result = StringUtils.commasToSpaces(message);
        assertEquals("33 333", result);
    }
}
```

build.gradle :-

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'

    // Unit testing dependencies
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Set this dependency if you want to use Mockito
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}

testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        // All the usual Gradle options.
        jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/androidTest/java')
    }
}

configurations {
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
    unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
}

dependencies {
    unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/results-tests")
}

task unitTest(type: Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    description = "run unit tests"
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn unitTest
```

I tried lot of things after googling more than a day, but test reports - xml/html are not getting generated. Please kindly guide if anyone has any idea on this.

**If i add below line then gradle sync failed.**

```
reports.html.enabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the line below in your gradle script?

`buildTypes {
    debug {testCoverageEnabled = TEST_COVERAGE}}`

Comment: This is not working for me. No folder is created after adding this code when using grade test. Using latest gradle version coming bundled with latest stable Android Studio on Win10.

Answer (score 0):

There is an export results option in the test runner. Once the tests have been executed, you can export these results as .html or .xml
It's the right most option.

[Click here to see where it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzd5d.png)